# Help with overlaping duplicaded mesh issues

Tags: mesh, sculpting

im still quite new with blender and 3D in general. I sculpted this armor for an academic project.

[image]

And now im trying to texture paint it, but wille i was starting to paint i noticed that some parts were getting the color and others dont, and i found out this detail witch makes me believe that there are 2 meshes overlapping somehow. I already tried to ose Merge by Distance and it didn't work. Can it be saved?

[image]

Comment: Did you try checking in object mode if the two meshes are duplicated? You might've accidentally duplicated your mesh in object mode instead.

Comment: ya that is my guess, in object mode i see many vertex where they shouldn't be =/ 
How do i fix this?

Comment: To do that, go to oject mode, and then select your texture paited object, and then select the object that is not texture painted. Then hit X>Delete. If you have more than one duplicated object, then you will have to select your texture painted object and then hit Ctrl+i to select inverse. Make sure you haven't selected any other objects except the ones you wan't to delete, or deselect them. Then delete the overlapping objects.